# Interpreting Strings as Variable Names (Classes involved) - Python

Tags: python, class, variables, eval, pyqt4

I have some strings of variables names, that must initially be strings (due to file IO).
The variables these correspond to are variable names of PyQt4 widgets, embed in two classes.

I need these strings able to be converted to the actual variable names to use them in functions.
(Kind of like how you 'int' a string of a number)

Here's the code (Showing the Class Madness)

**FIRST FILE**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.VariableName = QWidget(whatever)
```

**SECOND FILE**

```
from FIRST_FILE import Ui_MainWindow

class Start(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    def ResetDropBoxes(self):
        X = "VariableName"
        self.ui.X.Function()
```

*Some might recognise this as the format of python code generated by Pyuic4 (Qt Designer)*

The last two lines of the Second File are the trouble.
I get the error message "Ui_MainWindow() has no attribute 'X'".

I had no idea where to go with this, except an attempt with 'eval'.
I tried things such as...

```
X = self.ui.eval("VariableName")
```

This prompted errors "Ui_MainWindow() has no attribute 'eval'

```
X = eval("VariableName")
```

"VariableName is not defined"

```
X = "VariableName"
eval(self.ui.X.Function())
```

"Ui_MainWindow() has no attribute 'X'"

---

I could use any and all help for this matter!
I feel that eval gets me a step closer, but using these nested classes inhibits it!

HALP'?!

---

DETAILS:
- Python 2.7.1
- Windows 7 (32 bit)
- IDLE 1.8
- PyQt4
- Qt Designer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
getattr(self.ui, VariableName).Function()
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) for more info on `getattr`.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!

Worked perfectly, will accept ASAP.

Thanks x 100000